# Help with Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Define $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ by $$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&2n &&, x=\frac{1}{n}( n=1,2,...)\\
&0 &&,otherwise
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

Is $f\in R[0,1]$ ?

Proof: No, because $lim_{x\to0}f= \infty$. But how do I show that given any sequence $(x_{n})$ in $[0,1]$, if $(x_{n}) \to0$, then $(f(x_n)) \to \infty$ ?   Thank you.

Comment: Actually you don't need to find that limit. A Riemann integrable function should be bounded, but your function is not.

Comment: $f$ is not bounded because $lim_{x \to 0} f = \infty$. $lim_{x \to 0} f = \infty$ is exactly what I want to justify.

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = \infty$ is *sufficient*, but not *necessary* for unboundedness of $f$.

Comment: By the way, that limit equality is **not** true.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I get it!

Comment: When none of $x_n$ is of the form $1/k$ then the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

That is not true. If $x_{n}=0$ for every $n$ then $f(x_{n})=0$ for each $n$.